# Check a birthday against a future date

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

There are 2 variables in what I'm trying to do; age and number of years. What I want to do is check if someone will be 27 or not by July 1st, 2014 + x years, and if possible, change cell color depending on the result (Yes/No). I'm using the following formula to calculate someone's age.

```
=INT((TODAY() - DATE(1990,2,6))/365.25)
```

What would be the best way for me to do this?

Thanks

Comment: for excel check this link: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datedif.php

Answer (score 0):

You can find the date of 27th birthday by using `EDATE` function in excel, e.g. with `DOB` in A2 you can use this formula

`=EDATE(A2,27*12)`

So now you can compare the result of that against any other date, e.g. this formula in conditional formatting

`=EDATE(A2,27*12)>$B$2`

where B2 contains the date to check against